# Git cannot write to a directory created on a Windows network share from macOS regardless of it being macOS/Windows Git

Tags: windows, macos, network-shares

I have a Windows server which exposes a directory for sharing on the local network using the built-in directory sharing tools from Windows. This server has a user account on it which I'm using in all the steps that follow.

I am using a macOS laptop to connect to the share and mount it in Finder. For this I am using the built-in Finder Connect to Server functionality and filling in the Windows computer name and the credentials of the user. The share mounts successfully and stays mounted without a problem.

When I RDP to the server and created a directory there and run `git init` in it, everything is fine.

When I create a directory on the share from within VS Code running on the Mac that has the share mounted and then attempt to run `git init` in it on *either* the macOS laptop's Git or the Windows server's Git through RDP (which uses the same user credentials), both attempts fail.

The problem that is being printed is the inability to rename `.git/config.lock` to `.git/config` - the `.git/config` file is not writeable.

I checked the sharing permissions tab in the directory properties and the user groups, their permissions and even the owner field is all set to the same values across the working and the broken server and the values look okay to me.

It seems to me as though the directories created using macOS on the attached network drive get some permissions/ownership stuff wrong and as a result neither Windows nor macOS (presumably because it doesn't do the disk I/O directly but instead talks to Windows over the share protocol and asks it to do the I/O on behalf of the impersonated user) can write to it. Or maybe they can since the `config.lock` file might be getting created, just the write to `config` itself fails.

How can I compare the permissions/ownership data of the working (created using RDP on Windows) and broken (created on the network share by macOS) directories to find the difference and fix it?

Do I need to reconfigure my network share connection so that the user gets impersonated with the right permissions and I don't have to apply a fix for each new directory?

**Further Findings**

This is definitely an ownership/permission issue because the directories created over the network cannot be deleted:

[image]

`NUC\Tom` is the user used everywhere - in the network share, in RDP, on the Windows server and it is show as the owner in the Properties tab of the directory.

Comment: Seems to be related: https://serverfault.com/q/831089. Perhaps I should have asked this question in Server Fault.

Comment: This might be a bug in the macOS SMB client implementation with non-Apple shares? https://apple.lib.utah.edu/mac-bug-connecting-to-non-apple-smb-shares/